# Xamarin Forms create a label just below navigation bar

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am trying to display information to the user in all the pages of an application. I like the idea of Spotify where a label gradually appears just below the navigation bar when the internet is offline.

I cannot figure out how to implement such functionality like that. I guess the solution will be to use a custom renderer. But I am not aware how to write such renderer.

Currently, my tab page is like this. How can I add label below the menu so that I can display it based on some bindable property?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TabbedPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="StorefrontRetail.Views.MainTabPage"
    xmlns:home="clr-namespace:StorefrontRetail.Views.Home;assembly=StorefrontRetail"
    xmlns:cart="clr-namespace:StorefrontRetail.Views.Cart;assembly=StorefrontRetail"
    x:DataType="mainTab:MainTabPageViewModel"
    xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
    xmlns:more="clr-namespace:StorefrontRetail.Views.More;assembly=StorefrontRetail"
    xmlns:mainTab="clr-namespace:StorefrontRetail.ViewModels.MainTab;assembly=StorefrontRetail"
    android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
    xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
    ios:Page.UseSafeArea="True">

    
    <TabbedPage.Children>
        
        <home:HomePage
            IconImageSource="tab_home.png"
            Title="Home"
            x:Name="HomePage"
            BindingContext="{Binding HomePageViewModel }" />
        <NavigationPage Title="Cart"
                        IconImageSource="tab_cart.png">
            <x:Arguments>
                <cart:CartPage
                    IconImageSource="{Binding CartPageIcon}"
                    Title="Cart"
                    x:Name="CartPage"
                    BindingContext="{Binding CartPageViewModel }" />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>


        <NavigationPage
            IconImageSource="tab_hamburger.png"
            Title="More">
            
            <x:Arguments>
                <more:MorePage
                    Title="More"
                    x:Name="MorePage"
                    BindingContext="{Binding MorePageViewModel }" />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </TabbedPage.Children>

    
</TabbedPage>
```

[image: Sample image]

Comment: Just an idea, if you can change the frame of tabbar in custom renderer, then  you can move the tabbar a little up when you want to show the label and move down when the label disappear.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT How do I move the frame of the tabbar?

Comment: you have to create something like this http://venkyxamarin.blogspot.com/2018/03/xamarinforms-mvvm-custom-tabbedpage.html ...make it a view and then you can manipulate the page , but since the root is tabbed page no control like frame can be added in it

Comment: @ShubhamTyagi I guess there should be something that we can do to achieve the above behaviour in the tabbed page too. Let's see if someone else has the knowledge to do or not. Creating a custom view is not an option for me.

Comment: @JivanBhandari Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45748990/10539446), you change the Y of tabbar.frame.

Comment: @Jack Hua Thanks for that. I will try to implement using that.

Comment: Yes, you can share your solution here once solved.

Comment: @JivanBhandari Any update?

Comment: @Cfun I have not found a working solution yet.